# handling Camera button

Tags: blackberry, camera

I am working on a blackberry application which contains use of camera . the problem is when the dedicated camera button gets pressed the stock camera application gets called which makes my application to go in background and when it resumes it throws ioexception currently what i am doing is i am deleting my field with camera when app goes to background and  add it again when app comes to foreground.What i want to know is ***how can i handle that camera button in my application or is there any other way to disable it?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to handle that button http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Camera-Button/m-p/667791/highlight/true#M135304 i recommend searching in http://supportforums.blackberry.com for blackberry before asking